# Cannot install kali-linux-full in raspberry PI 4

Tags: linux, pi-4, kali

I have downloaded the image from the offensive security website and I got kali running but I can't seem to find a way to install the full kali package(kali-linux-full).

The packages that come bundled are limited so I was looking to install the full kali package but when I try to do

`apt-get install kali-linux-full`

it says `Unable to locate package kali-linux-full`

I looked at my sources.list and I see that I have kali-rolling and in my mind I should be able to find that package.
Is there a way to get a full kali linux installation on a PI 4?

Comment: kali-linux is not a debian package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Kali Linux website:

kali-linux-full

> When you download a Kali Linux ISO, you are essentially downloading an
>   installation that has the **kali-linux-full** metapackage installed. This
>   package includes all of the tools you are familiar with in Kali.

https://www.kali.org/news/kali-linux-metapackages/

Run the following command:

```
apt-get update && apt-cache search kali-linux
```

You should see the list of metapackages you can install.

[image]

If kali-linux-everything is listed, try running:

```
apt install kali-linux-everything
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead paste the text direct into to the answer.